# Restler always returns not found

Tags: php, web-services, api, rest, restler

I'm stuck here, in wamp I run everything and works fine, however, when I tried to install my api in a centos box, I always get a "Not Found" error.

I dont know what else to do!

Even the say/hello example fails...

Is there any specification of the apache requirements to handle restler?

Any ideas?, it is kind of urgent

say.php:

```
<?php
class Say {
    function hello($to='world') {
        return "Hello $to!";
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'restler/restler.php';
    require_once 'say.php';

    $r = new Restler();
    $r->addAPIClass('Say');

    $r->setSupportedFormats('jsonpformat', 'jsonformat', 'xmlformat', 'yamlformat');
    $r->handle();
```

.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

error:

**Not Found**
The requested URL /mylocation/say/hello was not found on this server.

Thats basically all  my code, if you guys think that jsonpformat might be steping in my way I could paste that code here.

When I type the url like this: `http://myhost/mylocation/` I get a json error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found"
  }
}
```

If I type `http://myhost/mylocation/say/hello` then I get the **not found** error, its like .htaccess isn't working.

**[EDIT]**

It seems to work if I add "index.php" to the url like this: `http://myhost/mylocation/index.php/say/hello`, but I can't leave it like this...

I got this from: [Restler returns 404 status code if index.php is not included in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796479/restler-returns-404-status-code-if-index-php-is-not-included-in-url?rq=1)

Comment: If it's urgent you should give us way more details

Comment: I'm done improving the question, however, I could really use some information about the restler requirements for apache and php, in case I missed some module or extension in my installation.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file seems ok, so probably you have a problem with `mod_rewrite` - [check if it's installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php).

Comment: In deed @moonwave99 I had to set de AllowOverride variable of the httpd.conf file to All instead of None

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, thanks everyone for your help.

The solution was to set the `AllowOverride` variable of the `httpd.conf` file to `All` instead of `None`. As soon as I tried that it worked :)

Besides the **mod_rewrite** of apache, I didn't find another requirement to run restler, if I do, I'll edit this and put it here.

I found that this is a common issue with **restler** and it might be good to mention it in the documentation, hope this can help you.

**PD**: I must say that is very annoying to be voted down while editing my question when it didn't even passed a minute since I posted it, however I did as fast as I could. You might say "why did yout posted it then?" Because of the restler requirements part, it doesn't require much detail to answer that...

Comment: Excellent. This is definitely something that should be made explicit in the "getting started" section of Restler. Thanks Daniel.